# How do I inherit from body-later loaded css?

Tags: javascript, css

I've made an application that has an element on the top of the document.
Right after this element I have another div.

When I press a button located in the element 1, a website html content is loaded into the 2nd div injecting all it's scripts and css into the document itself.

The problem is when these css interfere with my element 1 css. F.e: the website loads a css that changes the body margin:

```
body{margin:0 8px!important}
```

How do I evade this effect dynamically on my element 1?

I cannot do:

```
#element1{
    margin: 0 -8px;
}
```

on the element because it's not dynamic, any other website could use other parameters.

Any other approach?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `position: absolute;` although I can't see enough of your code to actually know it's right.

Comment: You can add a special css class to the body element after loading and write your css rules for children of that special class

Comment: Could you write an example @Salasar? I'm not sure that's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions in this case (which I know of):

First option - **Using an iframe**

Have an `iframe` element in your second div, You can load the other HTML site into the iframe. This way the scripts and CSS are not applied to the main website, in other words: The scripts and the CSS of the contending HTML within the iframe are limited only to the iframe.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='element'>
      <div><iframe><!--this is where other website fills in --> </iframe></div> 
    </div>     
  </body>
</html>
```

Second option - **Using CSS priorities rule**

As per the CSS rules, the file that is referenced last in the HTML document will have the highest priority. So your HTML must look like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='element'>
      <div> <!--this is where other website fills in --> </div> 
    </div>
  <!-- your custom CSS goes here.-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Technically placing your custom CSS anywhere below the hierarchy in the HTML will work.

**Note:** Adding your CSS to the bottom may affect the UI if the page contains lot of other HTML, Since the CSS is referenced in the bottom, your HTML will load first without any styles hence looks ugly untill the CSS is loaded. What you can do is have only those CSS which should overwrite the other website styles and place them in a different file and reference this new file at the bottom and have your regular file in top head section itself.

Comment: This won't work because the website doesn't fill the div when the document is loaded but when I click a button on the element 1, so the css that is at bottom will be overrided anyway once the website's styles are injected.

I can't make it as iframe because I need to control the elements of the loaded website.

Comment: @JesúsFuentes even if the website is loaded dynamically the CSS priorities will work.. Its not when the file is read.. its about where the file reference is located in HTML.. Also placing it in `iframe` will not take away the ability to work on the contents.. you can still manipulate the elements inside the iframe

Comment: It's *specifity*, not *priority*

Comment: @Reddy, yeah sorry I didn't explain myself that good. What I meant was that the place where the website is in (the div) will not have it's full propper css.
And about the iframe, if I click on one element from the iframe, wouldn't javascript pick the iframe element instead of the actual element clicked inside of it?

Comment: @JesúsFuentes The scripts has to be written with few minute changes to work with iframe elements.. For ex: your main body will be selected as `$('body')` where as body in iframe should be selected as `$("#iframeID").contents().find('body')`. So this way you will not have script conflicts...

Comment: Yes but what about events? If I click inside the iframe wouldn't it be returning the iframe instead of the element from the iframe?

Comment: @JesúsFuentes do you mean scripts like events delegation?